# No marketplace application on the Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've got the Android SDK downloaded, got a AVD booted and running, but haven't been able to find the Marketplace application.  Do the images available through the SDK utility not include a marketplace app?  If not, is there somewhere I can get it?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html) you can add the marketplace to your emulator. Don't know if this still works but could be worth a try.
Why do you need the marketplace for development anyway? ;)

Comment: I have an interop concept i'd like to try out.  This sounds like the way to do this, except that it only runs in 1.5/6.  No 2.2.  Any idea where that could be had?

Comment: Seems like you can only use this with 1.5/1.6. I cannot find any specific solutions for 2.2, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This 2 part video walks you through how to get the marketplace and the gmail app onto an android 2.2 emulator:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe-jA3l3QNA

This link also covers it (http://anythingsimple.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-use-android-market-on-android.html) but I found the video to be a bit more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Android source. Some of the "native" applications are included.

http://source.android.com/source/git-repo.html

Comment: I think Marketplace is one of the *closed source* apps that Google only give to approved vendors.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Ham is for 1.5/1.6, from the tags below the article you can go to [this page](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/search/label/Market%20on%20Emulator) where you can find instructions for 2.2.