# Android: Installing the Market app on the emulator?

Tags: android, macos, installation, emulation, google-play

I need to install the market app on the android emulator on Mac Os X. How can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/does-the-android-market-work-on-the-emulator

Comment: First of all I asked specifically for mac os x. Obviously before posting the question I searched and even came across your link..

Comment: Why didn't this answer work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/does-the-android-market-work-on-the-emulator/4583211#4583211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994923/no-marketplace-application-on-the-android-emulator/4402599#4402599), re-quoted below:

> This 2 part video walks you through
>   how to get the marketplace and the
>   gmail app onto an android 2.2
>   emulator:
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe-jA3l3QNA
>
> This link also covers it
>   (http://anythingsimple.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-use-android-market-on-android.html)
>   but I found the video to be a bit more
>   useful.

Answer (score 1):

The Market is not available for the emulator. It is only available for hardware devices that meet the compatibility requirements.