# How can you make the android emulator support speech recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech

I am writing an app which uses android's speech recognition. However my app doesnt run well on the emulator - runs fine on the mobile itself however.

On the emulator I get a red error message through logcat which says:

05-06 20:19:38.527: ERROR/SpeechRecognizer(1745): no selected voice recognition service

Does anybody know how to enable an emulator to support speech recognition services?

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your emulator image, can you install Google Voice Search as in Converting speech to text. The app is in the marketplace at https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch&feature=search_result. I think this is the only way to add the Recognizer Intent. Recognizer is not part of the base Android, it is considered an additional component that ships with Google Voice Search and is included in some phones.

But, people have still reported problems and suggest using a real device instead of the emulator. See
[Why is it impossible to use the Speech Recorder on the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472370/why-is-it-impossible-to-use-the-speech-recorder-on-the-android-emulator)

Comment: I cannot work out how to get the android marketplace on the emulator - and I cannot find a stand alone APK for the Voice Search!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994923/no-marketplace-application-on-the-android-emulator

Comment: If you are too lazy to do another long ceremony to solve yet another Google's riddles: You can access the Play Store from the emulator's browser, log in, and install all the apps you need. @RenegadeAndy

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue , I can do this in genymotion all you need to do install google apps on your genymotion full package as you can see it support **Google TTS** please have a look at this link

http://teckfront.com/download-android-4-3-jelly-bean-google-apps-gapps-full-mini-packages/

for others versions https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=5648