# Unable to detect speech on Genymotion with AndroidStudio on mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, genymotion, speech-to-text

I am new to Android world.

I am trying to write a simple code to display text on screen converted from speech (speech-to-text). I have come across various examples where a simple code change will achieve that.

However, when I run it on Genymotion emulator, it is not able to detect what I am speaking.

*(I had to install Genymotion because Android Studio's built-in emulator did not support microphone input)*

Tool: Android Studio, Genymotion emulator (VirtualBox 4.3.0)
OS: Mac OSX (EL capitan)
Android sdk on emulator: 4.4

Any guidance?

Comment: That will be my last option. I want to get it working on emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you make the android emulator support speech recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916521/how-can-you-make-the-android-emulator-support-speech-recognition)

Comment: Yes, been through that thread. I got Google voice search installed but that also doesn't recognize mic input.