# how to download adobe reader programatically if not exists

Tags: android

Now I am working on an application. Through my app users can read pdf files and if pdf reader is not there then my app automatically will install it from the site.
This is the code I used for reading pdf file.

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/sample.pdf");
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (list.size() > 0 && file.isFile()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My doubts are:

1. How to check there is a adobe reader installed in phone or not?
2. How to programatically install the adobe reader on a phone?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From your code some complication..

Use this code,

```
Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // No application to view, ask to download one
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("No Application Found");
            builder.setMessage("Download one from Android Market?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, Please",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            marketIntent
                                    .setData(Uri
                                            .parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
                            startActivity(marketIntent);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No, Thanks", null);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u very much.....i tested ur code in emulater...that alertdialog box came .and i press ok then it gives exception.. what u think...its because i tested in emulater..will it work in phone??

Comment: @sarath the emulator doesn't come with the marketplace application, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994923/no-marketplace-application-on-the-android-emulator

Comment: Have you downloaded Adobe reader by programming using this code?

Comment: when i worked in pc emulater its opening the file if installed the pdf reader otherwise app is showing a alertbox with options .But when I run it in phone app is showing file cant open. My phone is not having adobe reader so it must shows a alertdialog.But its just showing file cant open without any alertdialogbox

Comment: Its because your phone has a any pdf reader which can't able to open that file. Be sure the condition is only for check Intent type "application/pdf" not for application adobe reader if any application available on your device which handle this intent type then dialog doesn't appear.

Comment: please help me...how can i test this app in my phone??

Comment: Just make a simple demo activity and write code of catch block in onCreate of that activity and just run it in device. To check download dialog.

Comment: I did this but instead of launching the market with a specific app i put "market://search?q=pdf&c=apps" so they could choose.