# how to open android application if installed and go to android market if not install

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to make android button and able to launch other application if already installed and go to android market if not yet installed.

How to do this?

Regards,
Virak

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480045/how-to-download-adobe-reader-programatically-if-not-exists/9480211#9480211

Answer (score 36, accepted):

use below code

```
String packageName = "app_package_name";
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

if(intent == null) {
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+packageName));
}
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Would you be kind to explain why there is no `startActivity(intentMarket)` ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Cԃաԃ: This is probably late but it's already there in the null check.  If it's not null then we just use the package name.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Similar answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577377/9640177. +1 nice answer

Comment: Also you need to add   <package android:name="app_package_name" /> under <queries> section in AndroidManifest file if you are targetting Android 11 or more (or else getLaunchIntentForPackage will return null . For more details -  https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Answer (score 2):

Try with this -

Just create one `Button` in your layout. And, onClick of that button check below condition -

```
Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);
    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
              if(check() == true)
              {
                  PackageManager pack = this.getPackageManager();
                  Intent app = pack.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packagename);
                  startActivity(app);
              }else
              {
                  Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                  marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=packagename"));
                  startActivity(marketIntent);
              }
         }
    });
}

public boolean check()
{
    try{
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("packagename", 0 );
        return true;
    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the Application activity from your code using the, other application package name and activity name or by the Intent filters which is belongs to that other application you need to call...

```
    Intent newIntent;
    newIntent = new Intent("other application Package name","class name");
    startActivity(newIntent);
```

Check whether it is launched or not.

//If it is launched, don't do anything

//If it isn't, then navigate the UI to Google Play Intent.

```
  Intent googlePlay = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  googlePlay.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"other application package name"));
  startActivity(googlePlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside onclick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
  try{
    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("applicationId"));
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "applicationId")));
 }
}
```