# Check if Android app is not installed then prompt a toast message

Tags: android, webview, crash, aurasma

Solved With This: [how to open android application if installed and go to android market if not install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610646/how-to-open-android-application-if-installed-and-go-to-android-market-if-not-ins)

I need to check if an app is installed before start it, and if not prompt the user a toast message like "The app is not installed, please press on the Download from market" or automatically link to market.

My app (main) is a webview with 2 buttons:

1. Download the app from market (works correctly, html is < a href="inkstudio://market" >)
2. Launch the app (html is < a href="inkstudio://lancia" >)

If I press the button #1 (download) I can download correctly the app from the PlayStore, and if I press the button #2 the downloaded app start correctly.

But if I press the button#2 when the app is not installed, I get a crash.
How can i prevent this?

My code is:

```
if(url.equals("inkstudio://market")){
    Intent lancia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    lancia.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.aurasma.aurasma"));
    startActivity(lancia);
}
if(url.equals("inkstudio://lancia")){
    Intent lancia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    lancia.setData(Uri.parse("aurasma://?YXVyYXNtY"));
    startActivity(lancia);
}
```

Comment: take a look of this:  
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-if-the-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search in the installed applications programmatically in the device.
take a look of this:
  [How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-if-the-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android-programmatically)