# Dynamic link or App Indexing or App Invite?

Tags: android, deep-linking, dynamic-linking

If a user clicks a hyperlink it should take the user to the app if installed or corresponding app in the Google play. After installation the auto fill in the login page with credentials in the hyperlink.

To do this which feature should I enable - Dynamic link or App Indexing or App Invite ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11610829/940834 Here is an example of opening app or playstore.

Comment: I want to click a tiny url received via sms or email which include the user credential. Once clicked if the app is already installed it should populate the textbox or install from the Google play after installation the textbox should be auto populated

Comment: You cannot control someone elses app in that manner, entering text into boxes.

Comment: I don't want to control other apps. I will be creating an app with user login. Upload to app store. Build a tiny url with user info. Send it to user. Once the user clicks, the app should fill the login detail in the login screen from the hyperlink

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063750/940834

Comment: This won't take to the Google play if the app is not installed in the device.

Comment: You would probably have to do it in two steps. See both links above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive) will work for your purpose.

App Invite generally serves similar purpose, but a bit less configurable. App Invite has built-in people picker.

App Indexing is different kind of library.

As a bonus the Firebase Dynamic Links will work with iOS App, if you have one.